# Formulation Fenchel Duality for Convex problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What is the Fenchel dual problem for a general convex problem with constraints?

Precisely  assume slater condition holds in following convex problem

$$\begin{matrix}
\min & f(x) \\ 
 s.t& g(x) \leq 0 \\ 
 &Ax =b 
\end{matrix}$$

What would be the dual problem.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%27s_duality_theorem) I only see that Fenchel duality only works for convex **unconstrained** problems or at most with affine constraint. How can I incorporated nonlinear constrains into the dual problem?

Comment: Define $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x)$ if the constraints are satisfied and $+\infty$ otherwise?

Comment: @copper.hat   Then to Find conjugate of $\tilde{f}(x)$ we  need to solve an optimization problem with same constraints , so what's the point of duality ?

Comment: What do you mean by the Fenchel dual of a constrained problem? A Fenchel dual usually applies to a nominally unconstrained problem of the form $\inf (f-g)$. Without an explicit form of $g$, it is hard to see how you would obtain a useful form of the dual.

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Comment: @LinAlg Yes but that wasn't what I was looking for.

Comment: @Redshoes how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the Fenchel dual is
$$\begin{align}
&\mu^T b + \inf_x (f+\lambda g - \mu^T A)(x)\\
= \; &\mu^Tb-\sup_x (0^Tx-f-\lambda g + \mu^T A)(x) \\
= \; &\mu^Tb-(f+\lambda g - \mu^T A)^*(0)\end{align}$$
To compute the conjugate of this sum, use the rules
$$(f+\lambda g - \mu^T A)^*(y) = \inf_{y_1,y_2 : y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = y}f^*(y_1)+(\lambda g)^*(y_2) + (-\mu^TA)^*(y_3),$$
$$(\lambda g)^*(y_2)=\lambda g^*(y_2/\lambda)\text{, and}$$
$$(-\mu^TA)^*(y_3)=0 \text{ if } -A^T\mu=y_3.$$
After you substitute these last two formulas into the second one, you obtain the dual with variables $y_i$, $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Comment: What's the source of this definition ? and that infimum looks like a mess .

Comment: Just the definition of the conjugate: $\mu^Tb-\sup_x (0^Tx-f-\lambda g - \mu^T A)(x) = \inf_x (f+\lambda g + \mu^T A)(x)$. A mess? You wanted the dual ;)

Comment: definition of the conjugate of what function?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I suspect a missing minus signs somewhere, since the equality constraint should appear as $\mu^T (Ax-b)$.

Comment: @copper.hat good point! I updated the answer based on $\mu^T(b-Ax)$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark your answer as the correct answer 4 years ago. lol